# Stored procedure to drop tables: 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure to drop tables and keep getting this error message.
My code is below

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure AS
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1, table2, table3

END
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: Can you share the search terms you used in Google when you researched this error?

Comment: @dfundako I searched on the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Go
    CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure AS
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1, table2, table3

END
```